# Remove element that was added by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulties with jQuery when I try to remove an element that I used append to add. I've included my code below. I tried binding a custom event with live() and then using trigger() to fire the custom event, but the event never seems to fire. I also tried hiding the element instead of removing it, but that doesn't work either. What am I missing? How can I remove the appended element?

```
$('ul.chooseTags label.tag').click(function() {
    var tagId = $(this).attr('for');
    var tagSelectedId = 'selected' + tagId;
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $('input#' + tagId).removeAttr('checked');
        $('ul.selectedTags').remove('li#' + tagSelectedId);
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('input#' + tagId).attr('checked', 'checked');
        $('ul.selectedTags').append('<li id=' + tagSelectedId + '"><label class="tag"><span>' + $(this).text() + '</span></label></li>');           
    }
});
```

BTW, The checkboxes are hidden, which is why the click event is not bound to them.

Answer (score 0):

You gonna have to switch **'click'** to **'live'** or **'on'**

the problem is that the click event is not binded to the element you just created

if you are using jquery 1.7 or greater:

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul.chooseTags label.tag', function(){
    // code
});
```

otherwise:

```
$('ul.chooseTags label.tag').live('click', function() {
    // code
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work. You're using live() on an element that's part of the HTML, not on the newly created element.

Comment: If the idea is to catch the new elements then this is what he needs, if he has different selector he can use that in the live method and it will work, live monitors the HTML and is gonna fire even for elements created on the fly